# SAS EM decision tree bin vs leaf

Tags: sas, decision-tree

I recently did a decision tree using SAS Enterprise Miner.  In the results section, I can use the scoring ranking table option to get a table that has the following columns:

Target Variable,    Target Label,   Data Role,  Bin,    Number of Observations, Mean Target ,Mean Predicted,    Min Target, Max Target, Min Predicted,  Max Predicted,  Depth,  Target

Using this table I can create a cumulative lift graph.  However, there are many more leafs than there are "bins".  Is there a way I can see which leafes/nodes are in each bin?  I have over 200 nodes/leaves that the scoring results have pushed into 20 bins.